# row().child() is adding unspecified HTML in DataTables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

Using DataTables 1.10.18.

I'm trying to use the `.row().child()` method as described in the docs (https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child()) to add a child row to a table.

I'm using DataTables in `serverSide` mode but the rendered markup for a row of my table looks like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a class="expand-row" href="/get-data.json"> <i class="fa-plus"></i> </a></td>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar</td>
        <td>Baz</td>
        <td>2020-02-02</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I've written js which handles clicking on a "plus" icon which is rendered via the `.fa-plus` class in the markup above. This is a FontAwesome "plus" icon. js is as follows:

```
$('table tbody').on('click', '.expand-row', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = $(this).closest('table').DataTable().row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('active');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
    } else {
        row.child('Loading...').show();

        // Ajax request to get child row data
        $.get($(this).attr('href')).done(function(response) {
            // Add the child row data to the table and show it
            row.child(response).show();
        });

        tr.addClass('active');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
    }
});
```

This expands the row, shows the message "Loading..." and then makes an ajax call to the `href` attribute of the clicked icon, which in this example is `/get-data.json`. The intention of this ajax call is to get the data which is to be shown in the child row. It also toggles the FontAwesome icon to a "minus" to indicate the child row is visible (expanded row).

So far all of this works.

The problem I'm having is with the line:

```
row.child(response).show();
```

This works in the sense that it shows a child row. But the row occupies the full width of the table, which in this case has 5 columns. Assuming the ajax `response` contained the text "abc 123" the rendered markup is this:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        abc 123
    </td>
</tr>
```

`colspan="5"` is added by DataTables automatically because according to the linked docs:

> Each child row is typically contains a single cell, which has a `colspan` attribute set to span the full table width, so the content of the cell covers the full table width.   However, it is also possible to pass in a `tr` element which has multiple cells (one for each column in the table) to show the child row data in the same column structure as the main table.

I'm my case I want the markup to be like this:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        abc 123
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

The effect of the above would be that the text "abc 123" appears below the 3rd and 4th column headers because it starts in the 3rd column and has `colspan="2"` meaning it goes up to the 4th column.

I tried this which is based on the docs:

```
row.child(
        '<tr>' +
        '<td></td>' +
        '<td></td>' +
        '<td colspan="2">' +
        response +
        '</td>' +
        '<td></td>' +
    '</tr>'
).show();
```

But this renders as...

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">abc 123</p>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </td>
</tr>
```

...which isn't what I want.

It's wrapping a `<tr><td colspan="5"> ... </td></tr>` around what I've specified which means it doesn't render how I want.

I don't know how to fix this or specify that I don't want that `<td colspan="5">`. It seems that DataTables adds this automatically even though I've specified an exact string of HTML that I'm expecting it to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatables link you provided describes this.

https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child()

> ```
> row().child( data [, className ] )
> ```
>
> The data to be shown in the child row can be given in multiple different ways:
>
> - string - As a string, a single child row is create and the data is inserted into a single cell in that child row.
> - node - As a tr element, the tr element is used as the child row. This can be useful it you wish to define multiple columns in the child row.
> - jQuery - A jQuery object with nodes to be added. If there are multiple elements in the jQuery result set, they are added as multiple rows. If the node is tr element it is treated a the child row, otherwise a row and cell are automatically created and the node from the jQuery result set inserted into it.
> - array - Multiple child rows can be added at a single time by passing any of the above options in as an array. For example you might pass in an array with two string elements in it to create two child rows with the string content used for each.

You're passing in a string, so it wraps that string into the colspan tr

You should be able to fix this by passing in a jquery object so that it doesn't wrap it in its own tr:

```
var tr = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td colspan='2'>" + response + "</td><td></td>");
row.child(tr).show();
```

---

You mention:

> it is also possible to pass in a tr element

this is the 2nd option above, where you pass in a DOM node (a tr *element*), rather than a tr inside a string.  Possibly something like:

```
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
row.child(tr).show();
```

but the tr above will need extra work to createElement("td") etc to add the cells and response value you need (whereas jquery parsed string does this for you).